# Understanding electric power charging a battery

Tags: power-engineering

Let's say I have a machine that produces 1 joule per second. I then use it to charge a battery for 1 hour. The questions are:

1. Would the battery then have 3600 joules stored in it?
2. If I was to plug a device that used 1 joule each second to the battery, would it last for 1 hour?

(Assuming everything is 100% efficient and there's no loss of power due to friction or any other thing.)

Comment: It seems like you've grasped it. At least, the bit you talk about in your question.

Answer (score 6):

Your calculation is correct for the assumption that there are no losses.

Assuming that there are no losses reduces the value of the answer drastically. In reality, something like 15 to 30 percent of the charging energy is dissipated by heat in the battery during charging. The charging efficiency is influenced by the battery type and design, the charging rate, the ambient temperature, the age of the battery (number of previous charge/discharge cycles) and perhaps other factors. The charge controller also has losses that vary with design and charging voltage and current.

Comment: Also the battery may not “hold” the full charge over a longer period of time: many chemistries have a “self-discharge rate” which means that over time, part of the original charge will be lost.